# Custom Action modify files in Program Files folder

Tags: wix, windows-installer, custom-action, program-files

I want to create Custom Action that modify some files in Program Files folder

But when I run I got the error that the access is denied and the installer rolls back

running as Administrator also couldn't help.

is there anyway to solve this ?

Comment: Is your custom action deferred? Can you share the code you use to schedule the custom action?

Comment: Yes it is, luckily I found that I have to put `Impersonate="no"` to the action :) my problem is solved !

Comment: You Should post that as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @George Stocker comment, I'm putting my comment as an answer

For ones who's looking for the answer,

just put `Impersonate="no"` to the action :)